# Cannot execute JS function from HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason with this code it will not call 'createScene();' in index.html. I'm probably overlooking something very simple as I'm new to JS but I haven't been able to find anything.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pallidity</title>

    <script type = "text/javascript" src="Javascript/scene.js"></script> 

    <style type ="text/css">
    BODY
    {
        Margin: 0;
    }

    canvas
    {
        width: 100%;
        height:100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    createScene();
</script>


</body>
```

scene.js:

```
function createScene(){
       <script src="Libraries/three.min.js"></script>
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        //Bare minmum to render


        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x045f00 } );
        var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( cube );

        camera.position.z = 5;

        var render = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame( render );

            cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
            cube.rotation.y += 0.1;

            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

        render();
}
```

Comment: is the javascript file a folder called ```Javascript```?

Comment: Press F12 in the browser and look for enlightenment in the *Error Console*

Comment: Why do you have a script tag within a script?

Comment: What @Teemu said. I'm assuming this is the problem.  Probably has a syntax error in his console.

Comment: Or, remove '<script src="Libraries/three.min.js"></script>' from scene.js and add it to your html in head section and try

Comment: You could take a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Yep, I have an odd thing where I like everything to look very very neat.

Comment: @AlexK After digging through it it says create scene isn't defined? (It clearly is) "Uncaught ReferenceError: createScene is not defined"

Comment: @TheGuest No luck there, that was one of the first things I tried.

Comment: @BjørnEgil I based what I did off of that but I'll take another look thanks!

Comment: @RobNicholas you could have fooled me with that code ;-)

Comment: @RobNicholas How do you know that the function createScene() is not called from HTML? Because, if you call that function, what happens? Where does it renders? I don't have much idea in JSGL

Answer (score 0):

You have an html element (a script tag) as the first line of you createScene function. This is not valid JavaScript, therefore that function essentially does not exist. That's why it is not defined.

You probably want this line in your HTML file right before your scene.js script tag.